# C/C++ (Other Languages Too?) Conditional Early Return Good Code Practice

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, conditional-statements

Recently, I was reviewing some code I maintain and I noticed a practice different than what I am used to.  As a result, I'm wondering which method to use when performing an early return in a function.

Here's some example:

Version 1:

```
int MyFunction(int* ptr)
{
  if(!ptr) {  // oh no, NULL pointer!
    return -1;  // what was the caller doing? :(
  }
  // other code goes here to do work on the pointer
  // ...
  return 0;  // we did it!
}
```

Version 2:

```
int MyFunction(int* ptr)
{
  if(!ptr) {  // oh no, NULL pointer!
    return -1;  // what was the caller doing? :(
  } else {  // explicitly show that this only gets call when if statement fails
    // other code goes here to do work on the pointer
    // ...
    return 0;  // hooray!
  }
}
```

As a result, I'm wondering which is considered the "best practice" for those of you who have endured (and survived) many code reviews.  I know each effectively does the same thing, but does the "else" add much in terms of readability and clarity?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Right, I understand, but is anything gained readability wise by the explicit else?

Comment: I don't think it adds readability, but that's opinion.

Comment: I guess I'd have to amend that to say, it wouldn't add readability to a programmer(still opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else would only add clarity if the else clause is short, a few lines of code at best.  And if you have several initial conditions you want to check, the source gets cluttered very quickly.

The only time I would use an else if it is a small function with a small else, meaning less than about 10 source lines, and there are no other initial checks to make.

In some cases I have used a single loop so that a series of initial checks can use a break to leave.

```
do {
 ...
 } while (0);
```

I am loathe to use a goto which is practically guaranteed to get at least one true believer of goto less programming up in arms.

So much would depend on any code standards of your organization.  I tend to like minimalism so I use the first version you provide without the else.

I might also do something like the following in a smaller function say less than 20 or 30 lines:

```
int MyFunction(int* ptr)
{
  int iRetStatus = -1;  // we have an error condition
  if (ptr) {  // good pointer
      // stuff to do in this function
      iRetStatus = 0;
  }

  return iRetStatus;  // we did it!
}
```

The only problem with returns in the body of the function is that sometimes people scanning the function do not realize that there is a return.  In small functions where everything can be pretty much seen on a single screen, the chance of missing a return is pretty small.  However for large functions, returns in the middle can be missed especially large complex functions that have gone through several maintenance cycles and had a lot of cruft and work arounds put into them.